# Why does my virtual host XAMPP not be able to display the php file?

Tags: php, macos, xampp, apache

I am trying to set up a virtual host so that I can run my .php file from Eclipse as a web page.

I follow the instructions from this discussion:

[Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs)

Scroll down to virtual hosts and the instruction is basically

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Oky/Documents/eclipse/firstEclipseProject/"
    ServerName firstEclipseProject.localhost
    ErrorLog "/Users/Oky/Documents/eclipse/firstEclipseProject/logs/error_log"
    <Directory /Users/Oky/Documents/eclipse/firstEclipseProject/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The document is at `/Application/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Then I change the hosts file at `/private/etc/hosts` and at the bottom, I added

```
127.0.0.1 firstEclipseProject.localhost #firstEclipseProject
```

So, I think I am doing it right up to this point because when I fire my browser and point to `firsteclipseproject.localhost`, it redirects me to

```
firsteclipseproject.localhost/XAMPP/
```

which is the main XAMPP web page. It does not return an object/page not found which means the redirecting is somewhat working.

So, in `/Users/Oky/Documents/eclipse/firstEclipseProject/`
I created a php file called `HelloWorld.php` but when I point to `firsteclipseproject.localhost/HelloWorld.php`, it says object not found! I also tried `firsteclipseproject.localhost/XAMPP/HelloWorld.php` and it fails.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you ever get this problem sorted out? I have exactly the same problem and finding this question unanswered is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you leave the root directory the way it is and instead setup an Alias to your eclipse directory.

Comment: "This can be helpful if you're trying to replicate a production environment where you're developing a site that will sit on the root of a domain name. You can, for example, point to files with absolute paths that will carry over to the server:

whereas in an environment using aliases or subdirectories, you'd need keep track of exactly where the "images" directory was relative to the current file."

Thanks for the suggestion but I am trying to avoid aliases and simulate it like it is in production environment

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart apache after making config changes?