# Make aptana project folder runnable with xampp (php)

Tags: php, xampp, aptana

I've tried the following approach [Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs/1414#1414)
 but this doesn't work. I get a 404 error. Can someone give me some advice on how to run projects outside the htdocs folder?

Comment: or do I have to reboot for these changes to work? I just restarted xampp

Comment: No need for reboot if you restarted the HTTP server. Just check xampp for the button / menu to restart it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a file called `OK` containing the text `OK` into your new DocumentRoot:

`C:/projects/transitCalculator/trunk/OK`

Then open that file in your browser:

```
http://yourhost/OK
```

If you configured the document root properly (to that directory), the browser should display you a plain `OK`.

If not you need to check your server configuration again if the directory you specified is correct.

Comment: This is what I have been trying but without succes. Also can't find in the logs where the adress is pointing to..

Comment: Double check your httpd.conf where you actually set the document root to. Looks like that for your hostname the document root is not configured as you expect it. Are you sure you successfully restarted apache after you made the changes?

Answer (score 10):

RUNNING APTANA STUDIO 3.2.2 with PHP

I was just playing around with aptana 3 and xampp1.8.1. I couldnt just run my php project on aptana 3. so i found a solution, which is:

Select the following in this order: 
1) window>preferences>aptana Studio>web Server> 
2) New
3) External Web Server
4) name : Apache
5) base URL : `http://localhost/`
6) Document root : Point this at your htdocs folder that is in the xampp folder (in my case C:\xampp\htdocs)
7) start command : NET START xamppapache
8) stop command : NET STOP xamppapache

then click ok ok .. your server is set.

type a simple php command like

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

select run > run configurations

in the following menu use selected server and select apache (or whatever you named it) and 
apply&run. Your php should be working now.

you may also select "common" before pressing the run button and check the box near the green icon to place the apache server on your run as menu.

happy coding...

Comment: Any idea why i also get `Launch URL is not defined` ? Can you clarify what you said above `in the following menu use selected server and select apache (or whatever you named it) and apply&run. Your php should be working now.` Where is that option? In the web browser selection? Thanks in advance!

Comment: perfect answer to run aptana php files in xampp server. Thanks!