# how to change xampp htdocs directory in OSX?

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

I want to change XAMPP's htdocs directory. I followed the instructions to create a virtual host from this question:

[Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs)

this works fine on Windows 7, however when I try it on OSX, going to mysite.local just loads the xampp splash screen (mysite.local/xampp/index.html). I have restarted the web server. My virtual host declared in httpd-vhosts.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot Users/username/Documents/sitename.com

ServerName sitename.localhost

<Directory Users/username/Documents/sitename.com>

Order allow,deny 
Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Comment: The link provided does not seem to work anymore. I found an another article describing the process and also mentions that you need to edit your computer's hosts file: http://f6design.com/journal/2012/03/11/configuring-virtualhosts-in-xampp-on-mac/

Comment: Where did you change the user? @jela

Comment: where did you change the user?

Comment: search for "User deamon" and change it to your username - most likely you can get your username it with the whoami command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by editing httpd.conf

I have got this working. As per http://www.acwolf.com/blog/2009/February/xampp-virtual-hosts-mac, in OSX it is necessary to make two changes to httpd.conf, first, uncomment

```
#Include /Applications/xampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and second, change the user from nobody to the username you use to log into OSX. You may also need to delete your browser's cache.

Answer (score 23):

Open the following file in a text editor.

> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf

Search for "DocumentRoot", if the line below has a `#` in front of it than it's commented remove it and change the path between the quote

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
```

Now search for the line below and change the path between the quotes to your needs.

```
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
```

#### NOTICE: Paths similar to `~/` won't work use the absolute path.

Comment: If you only change these two setting it won't work. I am trying to change document root my self, but without success for now. Followed above edit, but didn't work for me either.

Comment: i can solve that problem with this answer. You also have to uncomment the first line to make it work. Mine is using XAMPP Osx 1.8.2-2

Comment: You will lose the phpMyAdmin in that case !

Comment: Make sure that your new root folder exists because if it doesn't, Apache won't start.

Comment: Im using MacOS Sierra and this causes an Access Forbidden thing to show...

Comment: @SumNeuron search for the "User deamon" within your httpd.conf and change it to your os user. you can get the os user with help of the whoami command. (I guess you figured that out by now but I hope it helps others)

Comment: use this to make it work. replace user name - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32963665/2444716

Answer (score 2):

I would like to expand this answer for 2022.

You will have to change 3 files if you want to keep web root in another directory. Let's say that you have installed XAMPP regularly, but your httpd directory is on another volume. Let's say in `work/xampp/`

Open `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` and change it to the following

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"

DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs" 
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/Volumes/work/xampp"
<Directory "/Volumes/work/xampp">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

We have added

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/htdocs"
```

and the block

```
DocumentRoot "/Volumes/work/xampp"
<Directory "/Volumes/work/xampp">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Open file `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and change it to the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/work/xampp"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost yoursite.mac:80>
    ServerName yoursite.mac
    ServerAlias www.yoursite.mac
    ServerAdmin webmaster@yoursite.mac
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/work/xampp/yoursite.mac/webroot"
    ErrorLog "/Volumes/work/xampp/yoursite.mac/logs/oll.mac-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Volumes/work/xampp/yoursite.mac/logs/oll.mac-access_log" common

    <Directory "/Volumes/work/xampp">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Open `/etc/hosts` as a sudo and add your new site to it

```
127.0.0.1 yoursite.mac
```

Answer (score 1):

If you forward to a directory in your user root, then:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/<your username here>/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/<your username here>/Sites">
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than the answers mentioned above, I also had to change the line in `XAMPP/xampfiles/etc/httpd.conf` where it mentions username. the default was set to `daemon` and I changed it to my username; so there was no permission problem.