# Setting up LocalHost server for MacOS Sierra to use PHP and apache

Tags: php, macos, apache, localhost, macos-sierra

**Note**:
I am not going to lie, I know pretty much nothing about apache, servers, local host, etc so please pardon my ignorance - if there is a comprehensive or a great review out there for these things, please point me in their direction. I did try and read some online tutorials such as [this one](https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/), but this all seems to be more than I need.

#### Context

I have some learned and then made some minimal PHP code that I want to test locally. However, that appears to mean that I need to use a server. Apparently LocalHost can serve that purpose. So I have made a directory `~/Sites` which stores different directories each housing a small website (each with subdirectories such as assets, css, js, etc and the actually html pages).

#### Question

How do I set-up whatever I need to set-up so that I can specify the root of one of this small websites (e.g. `~/Sites/a_website/index.html`) as the local host so I can see if my PHP code works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and download [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), which is probably the most popular local environment for development.

Once it's installed, open the XAMPP Control Panel, and click "Manage Servers":
[image]

Start the Apache Web Server. Your computer is now running as a 'localhost environment'.

If you go to your browser and type `localhost`, you *should* be greeted by a orange "Welcome to XAMPP" page.

In Finder, navigate to `Applications > XAMPP > xamppfiles > htdocs`, which is where you "create your sites". For example: inside the `htdocs` directory, I would make a folder called `test` which inside would be my relevant HTML, CSS, PHP etc - if I now went in my browser to `localhost/test`, I would see that site just like I would if it was hosted online.

---

Feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: Hey Zac, this is a good answer and very straightforward. Just one issue... When I click `Start` the Apache Web Server does not start.... Restart All, Stop All and Start All has no affect on the icon indicator either

Comment: Strange, never had that happen before @SumNeuron - after some research I think it is because there is already an Apache server running on MacOS: try entering `sudo apachectl stop` into Terminal to stop the process and then try starting the server again through the XAMPP Control Panel. If that doesn't work, upload your XAMPP log found in `Applications > XAMPP > Logs > Error_Log` to pastebin.com and post it here so I can have a look. Cheers

Comment: So the apachectl stop worked... but local host says "It Works" in black font rather than an orange "Welcome to XAMPP" page...

Comment: Also the directory `xamppfiles` does not exist under either User or System level Applications (`~/Applications/`  or `/Applications/`) Thoughts?

Comment: In regards to `xamppfiles`, I made an error in my original post - the path is `Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/` - whoops!

Comment: Not quite sure about the "It Works" page, try clearing your browser cache and reload `localhost`. Make sure you started the Apache server in the XAMPP Control Panel as well.

Comment: Ok, it is there under system's applications. Clearing the browser cache and restarting the Apache Web Server from XAMPP did not solve the problem...

Comment: Ok, so if I type `http://localhost` I get "It Works!" but if I then click refresh I get XAMPP...

Comment: Hmm - I guess try creating a folder in `htdocs` with a test `index.html` in it to see if it works.

Comment: follow up question, is there a way to get local host to pull from `~/Sites` rather than the XAMPP obscure - to me - path?

Comment: I think this should do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060533/how-to-change-xampp-htdocs-directory-in-osx

Comment: One last question - I hope - if I want to simulate uploading a file, does it just go to the directory on my local machine?

Comment: Hahaha no worries. Yes it will do, if you have a site that includes a file upload function, it will upload info that directory