# Enable directory/file listing in XAMPP

Tags: xampp

How to enable directory and file listing in XAMPP ? In WAMP it is by default enabled.

Answer (score 4):

My Xampp httpd.conf already had the Indexes option under the xampp directory entry
Removing all the default #comment lines, it looks like this:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But, I have my local root mapped to a different directory, outside of 'htdocs', (as per this post [Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs) ) so to enable this for all directories, I had to find the   entry just above that, and add the word "Indexes" to it.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Note I would never enable this for all directories on a production server, but locally it is quite useful.

Comment: I get a file listing when I browse from localhost, but when I try to connect from my phone at my hostname, I get a directory listing error. How do I enable this externally?

Answer (score 3):

Just delete or rename index.html and index.php files

Answer (score 3):

There is a [XAMPP Directory Browsing](https://github.com/kiranrs/XAMPP-Project-Directory-Browser) UI app, that will help you to browse projects inside **htdocs** in XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Open apache/conf/httpd.conf and search for Indexes in httpd.conf
And comment complete line like this:

```
#Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
#Options  - Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

Uncommenting First will enable the indexing of directories.
Uncommenting Second will disable indexing of directories
Removing the comment will enable the Directory/file listing of hosted path.

Answer (score -2):

Rename the 'index.php' file that sits in your htdocs folder to something like 'MODIFIED_index.php' (if you want to be able to revert to it later) - this index.php file is only used to point to xampp's admin controls that are found in 'localhost/xampp/' anyway.

Comment: I get a file listing when I browse from localhost, but when I try to connect from my phone at my hostname, I get a directory listing error. How do I enable this externally?