# Access forbidden and page not found error in Xampp server

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I have a database table that consists of 3 columns.
I want to incorporate a html link for each row in the 3rd column. I tried placing the link. But since I am using xampp server in windows, it shows access forbidden and page not found (i.e. error 403). I tried editing few of the php-config files, but nothing worked out.

Should I switch to WAMP server? Will that help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 403 errors, this post should have you covered: [Enable directory/file listing in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870560/enable-directory-file-listing-in-xampp)

For the 3rd column links, try pasting the `href` attribute of a link manually in your browser and see if that page loads. If it does not, re-check the integrity of your URL.