# xampp change document root

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp, apache

I have eclipse IDE and I have set up a workspace in "C:/users/matt/documents/web/". I set up a project called test in the folder test "C:/users/matt/documents/web/test". I have changed the Document root in the httpd file to "C:/users/matt/documents/web/" and the same for

I put "C:/users/matt/documents/web/test" into the browser but I can't access the files in the workspace, same for `http://localhost/xampp/web/test/`, `http://localhost/web/test/` and `http://localhost/test/`.

I'm out of my depth with server configurations, please help!

Comment: have you restarted the webserver after changing the document root?

Comment: SOrry for my answer I misread the question about the Document root and how you changed this.  Zolex was right!

Answer (score 20):

c:\XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot C:/users/matt/documents/web/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory C:/users/matt/documents/web/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Restart apache web server, then
...
Enter:
http://localhost/test

Check past  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs)

Comment: add closing tags at the end </VirtualHost>

Answer (score 9):

Restart your webserver after changing its config!

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you change DocumentRoot in `your\path\to\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf` as well.

Comment: I was (incorrectly) chasing 403 permission issues until I did this, thanks!