# Run my php files from outside htdocs

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, hosts, virtual-hosts

I have my xampp installed and running sites from the htdocs folder. I want to  create a website directory in a different location and run the files online from there.

I know I can do this somehow using both Virtual Host settings and changing my hosts file in System32.

I want to change my URL from localhost/websites/mysite/ to just mysite/

Can anyone offer assistance, thank you

Comment: just put you folder mysite inside htdocs instead of websites folder.
Check also this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157333/xampp-change-document-root

Answer (score 10):

Locate **httpd.conf** file on your local XAMPP install: 
C:\xampp\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

Edit the “**DocumentRoot**” line to the location of the remote **\htdocs** folder.

Example:
“C:/xampp/xampp/htdocs” to “C:/Users/Ann/Documents/My Dropbox/Dev/Xampp/xampp/htdocs”

Edit the “**Directory**” tag to the same remote location you set for DocumentRoot.

“C:/Users/Ann/Documents/My Dropbox/Dev/Xampp/xampp/htdocs”

**Save** the file and **restart** your local **Apache server**.

Navigate to your "**localhost**” in your browser and you should see the remote web site files.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to configure anything and then reconfigure ...

What I do is the following:
I have a simple PHP file in **htdocs** folder, named 'PHPexec.php', which accepts files from anywhere and it runs them as 'include' files. Example: Suppose you want to run "D:\PHPs\xxx.php'. You run **http://localhost/PHPexec.php?f=D:\PHPs\xxx.php**. PHPexec.php will receive the pathfile as a $_GET variable and run it as an 'include' file:

```
$file = $_GET['f'];  // After checking if it is set etc.
include $file;
```

Simple as that. From the moment you create your 'PHPexec.php', you have just to run **http://localhost/PHPexec.php?f={PHP_file}**. Your PHP file will be run as if it were stored in localhost! No configurations and re-configurations ...

(You can configure your 'PHPexec.php' to also accept variables to pass to the PHP file, etc.)