# htaccess for laravel in desired folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Does anybody have a proper htaccess for running laravel from a desired folder?
For example on windows, if I have a laravel installation in:
"C:\xampp\htdocs\www\larave\app2\public" how htaccess should look like in "C:\xampp\htdocs\" 
to url "localhost/" 
show laravel app in "C:\xampp\htdocs\www\larave\app2\public"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a document root change in xampp configuration. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157333/xampp-change-document-root) discusses the topic of changing the document root in xampp. After changing this, the webapp you working with should appear on localhost as desired.

Secondly, I would suggest to use VirtualHost in apache and update local hosts file to work with multisites in development machine. This [article](http://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wordpress-tips-webmasters/multiple-websites-xampp/) discusses the same in detail

Comment: thanks for comment it helps, but I was looking for htaccess solution, not changing document root in xampp I know for this. I don't know why I get thumbs down ;)

Comment: @fico7489 perhaps because htaccess is a really bad way to do it given the standard virtualhost option.  Also the English isn't so clear.