# (AvastSVC.exe and XAMPP) / (Virtual Host on XAMPP)

Tags: php, xampp, port, virtualhost

So I installed XAMPP and it worked fine at first (At least I think so. I typed in localhost and got the XAMPP page).

I have the files for the site I'm working on in my Dropbox folder so they stay up to date across my computers. I was looking for a way to point XAMPP to my working folder so I didn't have to work in htdocs and then move it back to Dropbox. 
I found this thread: 
[Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs)

And I followed cmcculloh's answer on how to set up a virtual host.
As the last step in his instructions said, I restarted Apache.
Except it won't start. 
I click Start in the control panel and it says 'Starting apache service...'
....and it sits there

After Googling about it I saw tips like disable make sure port 80 is clear and disable anti-virus. And use 'netstat -nab' in a cmd prompt to check if something is using port 80

Well AvastSVC.exe is using port 80. What I don't get is why it worked fine after I installed it, with Avast running.... But it wasn't until I tried to restart that suddenly Avast is getting in the way.... So I'm not so sure that that's the problem.

Maybe it's something I did when I was trying to set up the virtual host?

I just want to test php without uploading to a web server D=

Edit:
Oh and btw, I closed Avast and made sure the process was gone but it still shows up under 'netstat -nab'. I looked under Services and there is still an Avast service but it won't let me stop it =S

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for testing/learning/development purposes, perhaps you could try using [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) and set an alias to the Dropbox folder with the HTML files within. Also, I recommend you use port `8080` for development, not port `80`.