# How to run php file from other location?

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I have installed my XAMPP in C drive, normally, I save the file in this location **C:\xampp\htdocs** and run it as **localhost/example.php**. If I change my project folder to **E:\project\example.php**, what are the **settings that need to be altered in XAMPP to run the file from other saved location other than C:\?**.

Comment: You could even try to look it up in apaches documentation

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs

Comment: so why dont you just reinstall it in e drive

Comment: this belongs on server fault, since it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 6):

You can relocate your project by editing the DocumentRoot entry in XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf. There, you have to replace the line
    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\

With:

```
DocumentRoot E:\Project\
```

Comment: I also change the information,but i going to browser and enter the localhost/project/index.php it only show in html type(ex:the index.php file show the browser).but does not run the index.php.how to solve plz help........thank you....

Comment: If the document root is set to E:/project/, when you type the URL in your browser you have to type : http://localhost/example.php, because the root is not in E:/ is in E:/project

Comment: already i change the all possible,but they can't be worked,what are the procedure change the directory.plz tell me step by step.I change the DocumentRoot "E:/project".and run in localhost/index.php.But they can't find out the location.it will be show on object not found in the file error.

Comment: Follow this tutorial. Thus will help you certainly. http://mattots.blogspot.com/2009/10/changing-document-root-in-xampp.html

Comment: thank you,i solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial will guide step by step through this operation.

http://mattots.blogspot.com/2009/10/changing-document-root-in-xampp.html