# Redirect localhost subaddress to another folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My "htdocs" folder is set to this:  `C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs`
All my folders exist in subfolders of this folder.

I have such another folder here: `c:\MyProjects\project1`

I need to htaccess rewrite so, when I write: `http://127.0.0.1/project1/myfile.php`
On my browser, I will see the result of "myfile.php" inside "project1" folder.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

No, you can't rewrite a URI *outside* of your document root, `C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs`. And htaccess file sitting in that `htdocs` directory won't be able to point a request outside of the `htdocs` directory. Mod_rewrite isn't what you want anyways. You want to use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) from within the vhost config or server config. Something along the lines of:

```
Alias /project1 C:/MyProjects/project1
```

See also: [Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1408/851273)