# Can't open site custom path in xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

After installing `XAMPP` and creating index.php, I try open my index.php but write error:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403
>
> chat1.by
>   Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11

File httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPProjects\chat.by"
    ServerName chat.by
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPProjects\chat.by">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Projects\PHP\chat.by"
    ServerName chat1.by
  <Directory "C:\Projects\PHP\chat.by">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**But site chat1.by open normal.** May be I need add path "C:\Projects\PHP\chat.by" somewhere else?

File hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       chat.by
127.0.0.1       chat1.by
```

Comment: Maybe you have .htaccess which deny access

Comment: Maybe helpful: [Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1408/3361444).