# How can I start a laravel project outside of "htdocs" folder in xampp?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

Is it a way to start a Laravel project in another folder? For example:

instead of `C:/xampp/htdocs`

to `D:/projects/web/project1`

So after I download Laravel with composer to my `D:/projects/web/project1` folder I want to reach it as: `http://project1.local` in my browser.

I added 127.0.0.1 project1.local to my hosts but it only opens xampp in the browser.

Suggestions, ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to indicate to `xampp` that your site will be sited outside the `documentroot` folder (where all the sites in your server are located).

In your `httpd.conf` file add these lines, which will allow to you to access the site via `http://localhost/laravel.project`:

```
  Alias /laravel.project "D:/projects/web/project1/public"
    <Directory "D:/projects/web/project1/public">
            Options FollowSymlinks
            AllowOverride none
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

If you want to get access directly, via a uri like `http://laravel.project`, you must create a [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).