# Aptana using XAMPP server

Tags: xampp, aptana3

I'm using Aptana 3.6.1 and XAMPP 3.2.1. I know in order to work with XAMPP easily I need to put my files into 'htdocs' folder. But is there anyway that I can still run PHP scripts(usning aptana) keeping project files anywhere?
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put your project anywhere by using [these features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421/1820217). I recommend you to use the first way to do it which is Virtual Hosts. You can change your virtual hosts config to achieve it. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421/1820217) to see the details.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\Projects\transitCalculator\trunk
    ServerName transitcalculator.localhost
    <Directory C:\Projects\transitCalculator\trunk>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```