# Install Google Drive in localhost directory

Tags: google-drive-api, localhost

I use Xampp for localhost. I would like to have my files on localhost synced on different computers. I figure that I could just install Google Drive inte the Xampp directory eg. "localhost/Google Drive" (of course I will have to do this on all computers).

Before I do so I wonder if there would be any disadvantages doing so?

Also I wonder how to get "localhost/Google Drive/some-website/index.php" to work (note the space in "Google Drive")?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a local service that calls your google drive files by url, check the google drive [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/) so you can do this integration.

Comment: Maby I explained bad. I want to use Google Drive to sync my files on different computers (for this I am just downloading Google Drive from https://www.google.com/drive/download/). This works great. On top of that I would like to be able to test my synced files in localhost eg. a PHP file. By doing so I will have I synced development folder for all computers. If I change the PHP file on one computer it will be updated on all my computers :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't wait.

Works like a **CHARM**! Did not experience any disadvantages.

I solved the "Google Drive space problem" like this:

1. Quit Google Drive
2. Move the folder to your "htdocs" folder and rename the folder to eg. "google-drive" (my location and filename is "C:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive")
3. Restart Google Drive (it will say that folder could not be found)
4. Choose the option to relink to the new folder.

Since I installed the Google Drive folder in "C:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive" I have the option to work on localhost without syncing files eg. files in "C:\xampp\htdocs\my-uncynked-folder".