# How do I change a file path correctly in index.php file when localhost sends error message?

Tags: php, file, mamp, filepath

I need to connect my mamp-Database with the craftcms files, in order to create a new website.

I put all the files for the installation of craft in the requested files. As I wanted to open the link for creating the new page, i got the error message:

[image]

The file structure you can see in the images below.

[image: Now my question]

how do I change the file path correctly? Or how do I change the file structure, so the host will find it?

Thanks very much for you answer in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs)

Comment: no, unfortunately not.

I want to integrate the craft cms files in the mamp install files. but it shows that I got the wrong path for craft. (as seen in pic 1)

my question. what do I have to write in my index.php instead of  
" Path to your craft/ folder $craftPath = '/craft'; "