# On click can I open specified folder of my PC using PHP? And it must work in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

> Is it possible to on click event open computer directory using PHP.

```
<body>
    <a href="file://C:/Users/Pictures/">Link Text</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want upload file or?

Comment: Are you looking for [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)?

Comment: proofzy, i am not want to upload file. I want open specified directory then in this directory there are many file like .doc, .pdf, .xls, .txt, etc. now i'm select any file and open that file.

Comment: you can map directory in xampp or wamp config file and access it by relative path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can open files in browsers but keep in mind each browser has its own way to handle such urls. Old Internet Explorer 8 in Windows 7 opens links in Windows Explorer, but other most new browser use their embedded interface for same.

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/">Link to test data</a>
```

also take a look here to see how to create paths for directories in proper way:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/