# XAMPP - How can I execute PHP files from home directory?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, xampp, home-directory

I've installed XAMPP on my Linux computer and server and database are running. Now I have a question how to execute my existing PHP-Files from `/home` path?

So far I have saved all of my PHP files in `./home` directory (e.g. `/home/Path-to-PHP-Files/Development_01/....php`) and until now I have uploaded them with FTP to server. In order to save myself from constant uploading, I thought that usage with XAMPP is faster and more elegant.

I found out that XAMPP apparently wants to save the PHP files in `/opt/lampp/htdocs` directory. Unfortunately I can neither call my PHP files from `.home`-directory in browser nor can I copy them to `/opt/lampp/htdocs` because this path is read-only. 
How can I configure XAMPP to make my PHP files run in `/home` directory?

Comment: There is an `.ini` file you can edit to point to the base for htdocs. Im not verse with linux so i dont know what that file is called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make XAMPP/Apache serve file outside of htdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408/make-xampp-apache-serve-file-outside-of-htdocs)

Comment: @gre_gor: not really. Link refers only for Windows. I'd like to now usage for Linux.

Comment: Usage for Linux is essentailly the same, save for the path to the directory.

Comment: Where can I find `httpd-vhosts.conf` and how to edit?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `DocumentRoot` in your virtual hosts file, then restart XAMPP. Here is an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/Path-to-PHP-Files/Development_01/"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
    <Directory C:/home/Path-to-PHP-Files/Development_01/> # or a linux path
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Button "Open Conf File" allows only to edit `httpd.conf`. Where can I find `httpd-vhosts.conf` and how to edit?

Comment: You can change the `DocumentRoot` in the httpd.conf too. The vhosts file is in `/xampp/apache/conf/extra `